# KSOAP 2 with complex objects

Tags: android, soap, ksoap2

I have a problem with KSOAP2 for android with dependencies on an Android device.

I followed the instruction  from seesharpgears http://seesharpgears.blogspot.com/2010/10/ksoap-android-web-service-tutorial-with.html

I have a Embarcadero C++ Builder XE2 Server with this function to pass a complex data type.

The function is this:

I tried to create a dummy method witch returns back his request.

I created a class called Category.

But I don't know why, I am receiving still this data with data type vector:

Here my code:

```
public void getSettings(String sessionId){
 SoapObject Request = new SoapObject(ProgramSettings.NAMESPACE, "GetCategoryById");
  SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
  envelope.dotNet = false;
  envelope.setOutputSoapObject(Request);
  Category C = new Category();
  envelope.addMapping("urn:@:TrackNavMobile", "Category",new Category().getClass());
 // addMapping("urn:@:TrackNavMobile", "Category", cat.getClass());
  String url="http://" + readIp() + ":" + readPort() +"/soap/ITrackNavMobile";
  HttpTransportSE  androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(url);
  /*
   * Call the web service and retrieve result ... how luvly <3
   * 
   * */
  try
  {
      androidHttpTransport.call(ProgramSettings.SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
      SoapObject response = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;

      //TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

         for(int i=0;i<response.getPropertyCount();i++)
   {
             new AlertDialog.Builder(this) 
             .setMessage(response.getProperty(0).toString())
             .setNeutralButton("OKi", null)
             .show();

      //if complex type is present then you can cast this to SoapObject and if primitive type is returned you can use toString() to get actuall value.
   }

  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

This is the result with properties...When I am debugging it calls the setCategory method written in Java with the correct values...but it doesn't return them.. 
[Category : it.comtec.Category@44f02ea0, return : it.comtec.Category@44f02ea0]

This is my server dummy method witch is called:

```
 Category*  TTrackNavMobileImpl::GetCategoryById(){
        Category* setup= new Category();
        setup->Name="Thomas";
        setup->CategoryId=1;
        setup->Description="Test1";
        return setup;
 }
```

This is the RequestDump:

```
<v:Envelope xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
 xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"   
 xmlns:v="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><v:Header />
  <v:Body>
    <n0:GetCategoryById id="o0" c:root="1"    
     sessionId="FFEF196A3940136D7C141C4F01965D7D" 
     xmlns:n0="http://tempuri.org/" />
  </v:Body>
</v:Envelope>
```

And this is the ResponseDump:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"   
     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
     xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"   
    xmlns:NS1="urn:TrackNavMobile-ITrackNavMobile">
    <NS1:GetCategoryByIdResponse xmlns:NS2="urn:@:TrackNavMobile">
     <NS2:Category id="1" xsi:type="NS2:Category">
       <Name xsi:type="xsd:string">Thomas</Name>
       <Description xsi:type="xsd:string">Test1</Description>
       <CategoryId xsi:type="xsd:int">1</CategoryId>
      </NS2:Category><return href="#1"/> 
    </NS1:GetCategoryByIdResponse>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Someone has an Idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use getResponse()  instead of bodyIn. More details are on various blog posts linked on the site as well as directly on the wiki. You will have to implement the parsing of the response either manually or with marshalling.

Comment: Thank you for ur answer. When I try with getResponse I get during debugging in the bodyout.properties 
    setup->Name="Thomas";
        setup->CategoryId=1;
        setup->Description="Test1";

[Category : Category{Name="Thomas"; CategoryId=1; Description="Test1"; }, 
return : Category{Name="Thomas"; CategoryId=1; Description="Test1"; }]

but he doesn't marshal them automatically out.

Thanks

Comment: It will depend on you Category class on the java side if the mapping works. Check the examples about marshalling.. there are various links on the wiki.

Comment: Can u tell me the link about marshalling... do u mean this one:
http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/wiki/CodingTipsAndTricks
many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this has anything to do with your problem, but in your sample code where you are looping through the properties of the response and displaying them in alert dialogs, you are calling

.setMessage(response.getProperty(0).toString())

when it should be

.setMessage(response.getProperty(i).toString())

Comment: I had it before how u explained, then I tried to show Property(0) still for finding errors. Thanks anyway!